# How to make gravity function interact with my image game piece?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a simple html game using a canvas and I am trying to figure out how to use an image that will react to the gravity function that im using. When I dont use the image and use a box instead it works perfectly fine but when I use the picture it stays in one place and then will not react with the game.

Here is the code that I have......

```
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "ship.png", 10, 120, "image");
    myGamePiece.gravity = 5;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "#FF5733", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 300;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,         document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width,  this.canvas.height);
    }
}
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
        this type = type;
        this.score = 0;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        }
        else if (this.type == "image"){
            shipImage = new Image() ;
            shipImage.src= "ship.png" ;
            shipImage.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage( shipImage, 50, 50 )
            }
        }


        else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }


    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }

    }


    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        }

    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 175;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(30, height, "white", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(30, x - height - gap, "white", x, height + gap));
    }
```

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is from this non-functional snippet of code with syntax errors.

Comment: No syntax error. The code works perfectly fine

Comment: `this type = type;`, missing closing curly